# SSRS - Get LookupSet results on different cells

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, reporting-services

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious but I'm a newbie to SSRS (SQL Server 2012 R2) and SharePoint 2010.

My boss wants some basic reports from our internal SP site (list data) and I'm doing some research on SP + SSRS. Fields from more than one list are needed so I used the LookUp expression on Report Builder/BIDS to generate a sample report.

Here's the details. I've got two separate lists:

1. PROJECT (containing columns "ProjectID" and "TasksID") and
2. TASK (containing "TaskID", "Description" and "Hours")

I want to generate a basic report displaying the total Hours (mini tasks) spend on different Tasks grouped by Project, on which they are belonging to.

Here's what I got so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDFUS.jpg 
(bypass the Greek nonsense, its Projects - Tasks - Description - Hours)

For the last 2 columns I used the expressions:

```
=Join(LookUpSet(Fields!TaskID.Value, Fields!TaskID.Value, Fields!Description.Value, "Dataset2"), " " + vbcrlf)
```

and

```
=Join(LookUpSet(Fields!TaskID.Value, Fields!TaskID.Value,Fields!Hours.Value, "Dataset2"),"" + vbcrlf)
```

The result is an array of strings so as a first step I joined them with Join and separated them by newline. This messed things up cause I cant get the totals I need (total Hours spend on Task, total Hours spend on Project, total Hours for all Projects etc).

Are there any ways to get the results on different cells so I can work with them?

Thanks - Sorry for the big intro.

Comment: I think I'll have to code.. These expressions are too limiting.
Please guide me here: [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64422/sharepoint-linq-reporting-services-tools)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post that explains how to do this via code in the report: "Sum Result of SSRS LookupSet Function" http://salvoz.com/blog/2013/05/27/sum-result-of-ssrs-lookupset-function/

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Please note - I have not tested the code in the link as suggested by user24507.
However, if the link to 
http://salvoz.com/blog/2013/05/27/sum-result-of-ssrs-lookupset-function/ has broken & you need it - here it is.

Copy and paste this into the custom code section of your report:

```
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
If items Is Nothing Then
Return Nothing
End If
Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()
suma = 0
ct = 0
For Each item As Object In items
suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
ct += 1
Next
If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma 
End Function
```

To call the function in your expression use this:

```
=Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Parent_Number,Fields!Parent_Number.Value,Fields!StoreCount.Value, "StoreCount"))
```