# SharePoint, LINQ & Reporting Services Tools

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, linq

I'm new to SP and SSRS, so I want to check if my thoughts are correct.
Report Builder and BIDS suck on data retrieval so I have to go deeper using code.

Is it possible to write some code in **C# using LINQ statements** for retrieving multiple SharePoint content (lists) and create a new list, which I could use as a dataset for Report Builder to generate reports on?

In general, what are the steps **from code** (.NET + LINQ) **to report** deployment (using the visualizations and the tools of SSRS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you're going to want to create a Custom DataSource.

This post on StackOverflow asks pretty much the same question as yours (though generalised to more than just SharePoint as a source), with some good links in the answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891861/reporting-services-and-custom-datasource

Comment: I'll give it a good look, thx James! But I'm also curious about how people are using reporting services with SharePoint. Whats the process. The expressions of BIDS/RB are so limiting..

Comment: Depending on what version of SharePoint you're running, you could also try using the XML Data Source and hooking it up to the OData endpoints that SharePoint providers (check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff521587(v=office.14).aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fp142385.aspx in SharePoint 2013)

Comment: But other than that, and the standard SharePoint List data source, these provide for the majority of scenarios of getting data out of lists.